# Show PDF in Xamarin App from byte array

Tags: arrays, pdf, xamarin, xamarin.forms, stream

I am creating a mobile application with Xamarin Forms where the user can view the result of exams done. The result of the exams comes from a database in a byte array format and I need to somehow convert the byte array into a PDF and display it to the user. I saw that I can use a WebView to display a PDF, but would need to save it to the device and then display it. Would anyone know how I can convert the byte array to PDF and display it in a WebView without having to save it or do it otherwise?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for the answer but I'm still trying to implement this. His answer was the most promising one for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pdf.js` makes it really easy: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

1. Add a `WebView` to your Forms' Page and setup the dependency code to obtain the baseurl path per platform

   - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=vswin
2. Add the `pdf.js` and `pdf.worker.js` to your application projects (`BundleResource` for iOS and `AndroidAsset` for Android)
3. Convert your PDF stream to a Base64-string (via a `MemoryStream` if needed) and embed that string into a HTML-based string.
4. Use JavaScript (`atob`) to decode that base64 string and setup `pdf.js /`pdf.worker.js`to render to a`canvas` defined in your html.

### Example:

#### XAML:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="webViewContainer" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <WebView x:Name="webView" BindingContext="{x:Reference webViewContainer}" WidthRequest="{Binding Width}" HeightRequest="{Binding Height}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

#### Code-behind:

**Note**: Using a PDF via bundled resource, substitute your stream there....

```
            var baseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();
            string base64Pdf;
            using (var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("Dank Learning 1806.04510.pdf"))
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                base64Pdf = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
            }
            var html = @"
<html>
<head> 
<script type=""text/javascript"" src=""pdf.js""></script>
 <script type=""text/javascript"">
    window.onload=function(){
var pdfData = atob('SUSHIHANGOVER');
var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'pdf.worker.js';
var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({data: pdfData});
loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
  console.log('PDF loaded');
  var pageNumber = 1;
  pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
    console.log('Page loaded');
    var scale = 1.5;
    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
    var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;
    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
    renderTask.then(function () {
      console.log('Page rendered');
    });
  });
}, function (reason) {
  console.error(reason);
});
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>StackOverflow / Base64 PDF</h1>
<canvas id=""the-canvas"" style=""border: 1px solid""></canvas>
<h2>by SushiHangover</h2>
</body>
</html>
";
            html = html.Replace("SUSHIHANGOVER", base64Pdf);
            webView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
            {
                BaseUrl = baseUrl,
                Html = html
            };
```