# Show documents in WebView from byte array

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms app, I want to be able to display documents (.pdf, .docx, .ppt) that I have as a `byte[]`. I only need it to work on iOS devices. This works for me:

```
var url = "https://www.example.com/doc.pdf"
//var url = "https://www.example.com/doc.docx" or this
//var url = "https://www.example.com/doc.ppt" or this
myWebView.Source = url
```

And I can see the document in my `WebView`. But I need to be able to display it from a byte array. Something like this:

```
var pdfByteArray = GetPdfFromMemory();
myWebView.Source = pdfByteArray;
```

I don't want to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51449047/1136506) as it seems it would only work for PDFs.

Comment: write it to a file and load it as a local file

Comment: There must be a way to view it in a `WebView`...

Comment: load it in the `WebView` as a local file

Comment: I don't know how?

Comment: Don't know how to "what"?  Write a byte[] to a file?  Or load local content in a webview?  Both are pretty well documented.  https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+webview+local+content+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Ok that worked - thanks!

Comment: @Drake [From this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/74519/convert-byte-array-to-pdf-for-android-and-ios-in-xamarin-forms), you can use dependencyService to convert byte[] into pdf and save into device storage, then display local pdf in webview.