# How can I show a PDF coming as bytearray from some database in MAUI?

Tags: android, pdf, maui

I have read quite a few documents on the net, with no clear solution for me.

I get from the database via some API the name of some attachment (an image or a pdf file) and a bytearray representing that attachment.

On receiving it, I need to navigate to some "viewer" page where I should show those.

Image files are easy. But what about the pdf files ?

I have managed to show some specific pdf file like so:

In xaml.cs I have the code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly MainViewModel viewModel;

    public MainPage(MainViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
        this.viewModel = viewModel;

        #if ANDROID
            Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WebViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("pdfviewer", (handler, view) =>
            {
                handler.PlatformView.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
                handler.PlatformView.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
                handler.PlatformView.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            });

            pdfview.Source = $"file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=file:///android_asset/{WebUtility.UrlEncode("mypdf.pdf")}";
        #else
            pdfview.Source = "mypdf.pdf";
        #endif
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, I have set my xaml like so:

```
<WebView
    x:Name="pdfview"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    Source="{Binding Source}"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

and in the viewModel I have

```
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string source;

    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task<bool> ShowPDFBundledNewAsync()
    {

        #if ANDROID
            Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WebViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("pdfviewer", (handler, view) =>
            {
                handler.PlatformView.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
                handler.PlatformView.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
                handler.PlatformView.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            });
        #endif
    
        Source = $"file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=file:///android_asset/{WebUtility.UrlEncode("mypdf.pdf")}";
        return true;
    }
```

and xaml.cs contains this:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly MainViewModel viewModel;

    public MainPage(MainViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        _ = viewModel.ShowPDFBundledNewAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

It works.

---

Trouble is, I get the bytearray from an API call.

How could I modify the line

```
Source = $"file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=file:///android_asset/{WebUtility.UrlEncode("mypdf.pdf")}";
```

so that the viewer takes a bytearray instead ?

I have tried this, according to the advice given here: [Show PDF in Xamarin App from byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51446007/show-pdf-in-xamarin-app-from-byte-array)

In my VM:

```
[RelayCommand]
public async Task<bool> ShowPDFBundledAsync()
{
    string base64Pdf;
    string html;
    string baseUrl = string.Empty;

    var customFileType = new FilePickerFileType(
        new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
        {
            {DevicePlatform.iOS, new[] { "com.adobe.pdf"} },
            {DevicePlatform.Android, new[] { "application/pdf"} },
        });

    FileResult? fileResult = await FilePicker.PickAsync(
        new PickOptions
        {
            FileTypes = customFileType,
        });

    if (fileResult != null)
    {
        byte[] myImageBytes = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(fileResult.FullPath);
        base64Pdf = Convert.ToBase64String(myImageBytes.ToArray());

        if (base64Pdf != null)
        {
            html = @"
                <html>
                <head>
                <script type=""text/javascript"" src=""pdf.js""></script>
                    <script type=""text/javascript"">
                    window.onload=function()
                    {
                        var pdfData = atob('ToBeReplaced');
                        var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];
                        pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'pdf.worker.js';
                        var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({data: pdfData});
                        loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
                        console.log('PDF loaded');
                        var pageNumber = 1;
                        pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
                        console.log('Page loaded');
                        var scale = 1.5;
                        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
                        var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
                        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                        canvas.height = viewport.height;
                        canvas.width = viewport.width;
                        var renderContext = {
                            canvasContext: context,
                            viewport: viewport
                        };
                            var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
                            renderTask.then(function () {
                                console.log('Page rendered');
                            });
                        });
                    }, function (reason) {
                        console.error(reason);
                    });
                }
                </script>
                </head>
                <body>
                <h1>StackOverflow / Base64 PDF</h1>
                <canvas id=""the-canvas"" style=""border: 1px solid""></canvas>
                <h2>by ToBeReplaced</h2>
                </body>
                </html>
                ";

            html = html.Replace("ToBeReplaced", base64Pdf);

            HtmlWebViewSource = new HtmlWebViewSource
            {
                BaseUrl = baseUrl,
                Html = html
            };
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

and in my xaml:

```
<StackLayout
    x:Name="webViewContainer"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <WebView
        x:Name="pdfview"
        BindingContext="{x:Reference webViewContainer}"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        Source="{Binding HtmlWebViewSource}"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    <Button Command="{Binding ShowPDFBundledCommand}" Text="Bundled" />
</StackLayout>
```

Nothing is showing, even though my bytearray is inside the html.

I have also tried with

```
base64Pdf = WebUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToBase64String(myImageBytes.ToArray()));
```

in the ShowPDFBundledAsync() above.

How can I solve this problem, please ? I repeat - I get the bytearray from some API call, and the view must show that pdf on appearing.

Comment: Why don’t you just write the byte[] to a temp file?

Comment: Thanks, Jason, I have considered this, but a) it seemed to me to be quite ugly as a hack b) I have a bytearray - why would I write it to a file only to read it back again.... to a byteArray ? It would be like "I buy a book from the bookstore, but before I read it, I copy it by hand, and then I read the copies" c) I honestly don't know how to write a file, using the FileSystem Helpers, to the specific folder "Resources/Raw" :-(  I hope there is a way to solve this problem without jumping thru these hoops.

Comment: AFAIK pdf.js is designed to work with files/urls, not byte[], so writing to a file would make sense to me.  You don't write files to `Resources/Raw` - that is only for files that are bundled with your app.

Comment: I made it happen, finally, by saving the incoming bytearray to a file in the Cache subfolder and then reading that file in the webView. It works, but it's awkward. Plus, I will have to take care to clean that folder on the Back button, and also on successful login (in case the previous session ended abruptly). Anyway, at least I'm done with that. Thank you !